# Как убрать неиспользуемые сетевые интерфейсы?

Tags: linux, centos, сеть, ipv6

CentOS 7.2

```
$ uname -a
Linux host.network 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #7 SMP Wed Jan 27 18:05:09 CET 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Сетевые интерфейсы:

```
[root@host ~]# ip a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN
    link/ether 8a:51:05:fb:9e:35 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN
    link/ether 3e:4a:a2:c1:3c:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: ifb0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 32
    link/ether 6e:2c:19:2a:64:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: ifb1: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 32
    link/ether 12:a9:fd:3e:82:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:c4:7a:0c:94:81 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 123.123.123.101/24 brd 123.123.123.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 123.123.123.102/32 brd 123.123.123.102 scope global eth0:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 123.123.123.103/32 brd 123.123.123.103 scope global eth0:1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:c6:7a:2c:94:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: teql0: <NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 100
    link/void
9: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
10: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
11: ip6tnl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
```

Как убрать эти лишние интерфейсы? Мне нужны только eth0 и lo.

Подозревал ipv6, но у меня:

- `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

  ```
  net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
  net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
  ```
- `/etc/sysconfig/network`:

  ```
  NETWORKING_IPV6=no
  ```
- `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`:

  ```
  DEVICE=eth0
  BOOTPROTO=static
  IPADDR=123.123.123.101
  NETMASK=255.255.255.0
  ONBOOT=yes
  GATEWAY=123.123.123.1

  IPV6INIT=no
  IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
  ```

тут что-то непонятное

```
$ lsmod
libkmod: kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory
```

Чую. что собрали мне ядро с какими-то туннелями для ipv6... но не нужны они мне, а эти интерфейсы вылезли в одной серверной статистике и маячат там, хочется их прибить.

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса, список загруженных модулей (`$ lsmod`) и содержимое всех файлов `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg*`. внести изменения можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

> could not open /proc/modules

вот и корень «проблемы»: программа *linux* собрана «целиком», без выноса редко используемого кода в подгружаемые по требованию модули.

поэтому сразу при инициализации программы создаются все эти «лишние» интерфейсы.

вариантов выхода я вижу как минимум два:

1. пересобрать программу *linux*, включив «назад» поддержку динамически загружаемых модулей (нынче это стандарт де-факто в дистрибутивах общего назначения, к которым относится и *centos*).
2. пересобрать программу *linux*, вообще убрав ту функциональность, которая «ведает» этими «лишними» сетевыми интерфейсами (такая «уборка» — занятие довольно муторное и кропотливое).